Youtube crappy quality after upload
I made a PNG sequence video to mimic a write on effect. Problem is, it looks very good on my pc. But when I See it on youtube, the quality is horrendous. I've attached various timestamps of the video to show how it looks fine in one timestamp (00:05) and it looks so bad in one timestamp (00:04). Honestly, this is very troubling and I Tried everything - from outputting from premier pro via prores, h264/h265 (highest settings), but Youtube still keeps pulling this crap out of nowhere. What's the problem here? I Dont understand why its screwing up parts of video in one time and the rest?
I'm attaching screenshots here (please view full images) of the various timestamps, and the quality is all over the place and odd. its worse in some, and good in some. for example the white lines look horrendous (00:07 timestamp) although the quality is 720p.
what settings do I apply to export via premiere pro or do I use any other way?



This the link to the video: 



What exactly does "they look horrendous" mean? Are there artifacts? Are those artifacts in your original video? Are their in the original images?
